# lambda logs are going to cloudwatch after applying deny policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I create a test lambda on aws and apply following policy to stop logs on cloudwatch

It was working on this and logs was not going on cloudwatch. But when applied same policy on production lambda it was not working and logs was going to cloudwatch

I create a test lambda on aws and apply following policy to stop logs on cloudwatch

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It was working on this and logs was not going on cloudwatch. But when applied same policy on production lambda it was not working and logs was going to cloudwatch

Comment: You don't need to deny anything. Just don't give any logging permissions to the IAM role associated with the Lambda function.

Comment: Depends how you create that Lambda, a lot of IaC frameworks and also AWS web console, grants by default access to CloudWatch, so you might still need to change IAM permissions but as said above, to simply not grant access instead of denying